# PEX executable VS 2015 RC

Tags: pex

Is there a command line or API method to run explorations and generate tests for PEX in VS 2015?  The docs for the previous version refer to a [command line mode](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/command%20line.html) via pex.exe.  There is a Microsoft.pex.exe that is installed with VS 2015 RC but when you run it it responds:

```
launched Pex 14.0.22823.1 x64/IA64 Edition on .NET v4.0.30319

Instrumentation Driver Configuration error: Microsoft.Pex.exe is an internal exe
cution driver and should not be called directly, use pex.exe instead.
```

But I can't see a pex.exe installed anywhere by 2015 RC

Comment: Just curious: is there a specific scenario you're looking for that may be available in command line pex.exe but missing in the VS 2015/Intellitest?

Comment: I've got a few hundred legacy classes I want to add tests to, so I was hoping for a way to script it rather than having to do it through the UI.

Comment: If the classes are under the same namespace, you can try "Run Intellitest"   on the namespace. It will run exploration on every class in the namespace.

Comment: Can you point me to where the option to run against a namespace has gone in 2015?

Comment: Right click on the namespace in editor and "run intellitest" should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2015 RC doesn't support running pex from command line.